# PHP fat-free-framework not route under https redirect

Tags: php, https, routes, fat-free-framework

I tried to setup PHP Fat-free framework(f3) work under https, but failed. I had used f3 routes under http and it worked fine on a Debian 10 + apache2 + PHP 7.3 environment. Recently I add a self-signed ssl on apache, then all f3 routes became '404 not found on this server' except the root one($f3->route('GET /',...);).

The apache rewrite engine for f3 routes woked fine under http protocol. The rewrite rules comes from f3 official suggestion(https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#SampleApacheConfiguration), and it was set in a .htaccess file which is under 2 level sub directory of site document root. I add 'RewriteBase /foo/bar/' after 'RewriteEngine On' in .htaccess.

These example f3 routes code is in index.php. They all worked under http protocol, only 'GET /' can worked under https connection.

- http work, https work too. print a 'hello world' like template.

```
$f3->route('GET /', function($f3){
    $f3->set('name', 'f3-routing');
    $template = \Template::instance();
    echo $template->render('std2.html');
});
```

- http work, print 'test1'; https not work, display URL not found on this server.

```
$f3->route('GET /test1', function(){echo "test1";});
```

- http work, print a 'hello world' like template; https not work, display URL not found on this server.

```
$f3->route(array('GET /@conf_id/@room_id'),
    function($f3, $params) {
        $template = \Template::instance();
        echo $template->render('disp_ppt.html');
    }
);
```

Comment: the SSL website usually has a different config file in apache.. https.conf ..compare it with your http.conf and make the changes you need to get it running.. it's probably something like "AllowOverwrite all" that is not present in your https apache config for this host.

Answer (score 0):

According to @ikkez 's suggestion. It seems work. But there is a little difference. The SSL config file in Debian 10 Apache2 is locate in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf. It seems no place to add "AllowOverwrite all". Although I have "AllowOverwrite all" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, and I think it should work, but it doesn't. What finally make the rewrite routes work is updating /etc/apache2/apache2.conf from "AllowOverwrite None" to "AllowOverwrite all".
I think the reason is: when system run http protocol, config file will direct to use 000-default.conf; when system run https protocol, config file direct to default-ssl.conf. This change make AllowOverwrite not work under https. Updating apache2.conf "AllowOverwrite all" made a global config.